# netsuite add back order quantity to invoice advanced pdf template

Tags: html, templates, pdf, netsuite, freemarker

I would like to add back order quantity to the invoice line items but the field doesn't appear in the template editor.  How can I add the field?

Answer (score 0):

SuiteAnswers suggests that you use a [custom field](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/81544/kw/add%20back%20order%20quantity%20to%20pdf%20template) but I found that this did not return the value for the sales order - perhaps it returns the back order amount for an item, not a sales item.

I tried using the Chrome plugin NetSuite Field Explorer on the invoice form to see what field name NetSuite is using.  The sales order lines are kept in a separate lineItem field and that doesn't appear to be available in the template editor.  The NetSuite Field Explorer has a link which takes you to the record definition of the invoice record type.  On that [page](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_2/script/record/invoice.html) the back ordered field is listed as quantityremaining.  Plugging that into the template resulted in the display of the correct information, despite the template editor not recognizing the field (when it does, it displays the description otherwise, it just displays the freemarker markup):

```html
${item.quantityremaining}
```